# Self created image rotating method being inconsistent

Tags: python, image-processing

I am making a program that rotates an image either clockwise or counter-clockwise given a file path by turning the image into a 2 dimensional numpy array and rotating it. I can rotate the image clockwise (works repeatedly); however the counter-clockwise rotation (rotate_Counter()) only works on the first run and any future call of rotate_Counter() will rotate the image clockwise (or unrotate it). I have imported Image from PIL and numpy as np. The image is saved to the same location as the original image (path is used for both importing the image and saving the image).

I have tried changing the variable names in each rotation method thinking it might be a memory error regarding the new_image variable I had in both methods (changed to image2 and image3) and I have tried resetting the widthiterator variable multiple times in case there was an error with that.

A friend of mine mentioned that it might be a case of the starting point of iteration through the image array doesn't reset after the first counter-clockwise image rotation however the same error occurs if I run the method twice in the same run instance, run the whole program twice (each time only one rotation called), and restarting the IDE in between runs, which should cover that possibility.

My theory was that it had to do with the path of the image where  the system memory remembered the original image and when calling the second counter-clockwise rotation would import the unrotated image instead, but that would lead to the second run saving the same image as the first run.

Is there anything else I might be missing?

This is my first post on this forum so I apologize if there are any formalities I'm missing and feel free to ask questions.

```
path = "Insert_Path_Here"
image = Image.open(path)

class Image_Processer:
    def __init__(self, image, path):
        self.image = image
        self.data = np.asarray(image)
        self.data_type = type(self.data)
        self.data_shape = self.data.shape
        self.path = path

    #Rotates the image Clockwise
    def rotate_Clockwise(self):
        print("Rotating Clockwise")
        size = [len(self.data[0]), len(self.data)]                                          #Width, Height
        image2 = []                                                                         #Creates the new image list
        for i in range(0,size[0]):                                                          #Creates the rows in the new image based on the height of the given image
            image2.append([]) 

        heightiterator = size[1]-1                                                          #Starting at the last row
        widthiterator = size[0]-1                                                           #Start at last element of each row
        while heightiterator >= 0:                                                          #For each row in the image
            widthiterator = size[0]-1                                                           #Start at last element of each row
            while widthiterator >= 0:                                                       #While in the row
                image2[widthiterator].append(self.data[heightiterator][widthiterator])      #Each column should go in one row
                widthiterator -= 1                                                          #Move one element
            heightiterator -= 1                                                             #Moves up one row
        return np.asarray(image2)                                                           #Returns the new image as a numpy array

    #Rotates the image Counter-Clockwise
    def rotate_Counter(self):
        print("Rotating Counter-Clockwise")
        size = [len(self.data[0]), len(self.data)]                                          #Width, Height
        image3 = []                                                                         #Creates the new image list
        for i in range(0,size[0]):                                                          #Creates the rows in the new image based on the height of the given image
            image3.append([])

        heightiterator = 0                                                                  #Starting at the first row
        widthiterator = 0                                                                   #Start at the first element of each row
        while heightiterator < size[1]:                                                     #For each row in the image
            widthiterator = 0                                                               #Start at the first element of each row
            while widthiterator < size[0]:                                                  #While in the row
                image3[widthiterator].append(self.data[heightiterator][widthiterator])      #Each column should go in one row
                widthiterator += 1                                                          #Move one element
            heightiterator += 1                                                             #Moves down one row                                                               
        return np.asarray(image3)                                                           #Returns the new image as a numpy array

    def save_image(self, new_image):                                                        #Saves the new image in place of the old image
        self.image = Image.fromarray(new_image)
        self.image.save(path)
        time.sleep(1)                                                                       #Waits 1 second

image1 = Image_Processer(image, path)
#image1.save_image(image1.rotate_Clockwise())
image1.save_image(image1.rotate_Counter())
```

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: code could be simpler if you would use `for`-loops` instead of `while`-loops

Comment: when you save then you assign new image to `self.image` but you don't change `self.data` - so maybe later you rotate the same image in `self.data`. You may need to do `self.data = np.asarray(image)` and `self.data_shape = self.data.shape` when you save.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @furas I plan to switch to for loops after the program finishes working, but I used while loops because I started making the program thinking it would be easy to keep track of where I am.

Comment: Wouldn't the self.data update not matter unless I call the method twice? The bug has occurred even when running the whole program twice meaning that the values of the class variables shouldn't matter because they update themselves on the second program run.

Comment: it sets `self.data` only when you run `Image_Processer(image, path)` and later you always have the same values in `self.data`. If you run all code again then it has no matter but this shouldn't make problem.

Comment: BTW: Counter-Clockwise uses wrong values and it creates mirrored image.

Comment: BTW: numpy has [rot90](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.rot90.html). Besides `PIL` also have own function to rotate. And both may work faster.

Comment: I found problem - you have to use negative `image3[-widthiterator]` instead of `image3[widthiterator]`

Answer (score 0):

You assign values in wrong place and you get `transpose` instead `rotate`.

And when you run two times `transponse` then you get the same image.

You have to use `[width-widthiterator-1]` instead of `[widthiterator]`,
or shorter `[-widthiterator]`

`minus` in first `[widthiterator]`

```
image3[-widthiterator].append(self.data[heightiterator][widthiterator])
```

or `minus` in second `[widthiterator]`

```
image3[widthiterator].append(self.data[heightiterator][-widthiterator])
```

---

```
def rotate_Counter(self):
    print("Rotating Counter-Clockwise")
    size = [len(self.data[0]), len(self.data)]                                          #Width, Height
    image3 = []                                                                         #Creates the new image list
    for i in range(0,size[0]):                                                          #Creates the rows in the new image based on the height of the given image
        image3.append([])

    heightiterator = 0                                                                  #Starting at the first row
    widthiterator = 0                                                                   #Start at the first element of each row
    while heightiterator < size[1]:                                                     #For each row in the image
        widthiterator = 0                                                               #Start at the first element of each row
        while widthiterator < size[0]:                                                  #While in the row
            image3[-widthiterator].append(self.data[heightiterator][widthiterator])     #Each column should go in one row
            widthiterator += 1                                                          #Move one element
        heightiterator += 1                                                             #Moves down one row                                                               
    return np.asarray(image3)                                                           #Returns the new image as a numpy array
```

---

**EDIT:**

The same with `for`-loops

```
    def rotate_Clockwise(self):
        print("Rotating Counter-Clockwise")
        
        height = self.data_shape[0]
        width  = self.data_shape[1]

        new_image = []
        for x in range(width):
            new_image.append([])

        for y in range(height):
            for x in range(width):
                new_image[x].append(self.data[-y][x])   # [-y]

        return np.asarray(new_image)

    def rotate_Counter(self):
        print("Rotating Counter-Clockwise")
        
        height = self.data_shape[0]
        width  = self.data_shape[1]

        new_image = []
        for x in range(width):
            new_image.append([])

        for y in range(height):
            for x in range(width):
                new_image[x].append(self.data[y][-x])   # [-x]

        return np.asarray(new_image)
```

If you use `self.data[y][x]` then you get standard `transposition` around point `(left,top)`.

If you use `self.data[-y][-x]` then you get non-standard `transposition` around point `(right, top)`.

---

If you use `self.data[-x][y]` then you get flip vertical.

If you use `self.data[x][-y]` then you get flip horizontal.

Interesting result gives also `data[ (y+100) % height ][x]` or `data[y][(x + 100) % width]`- it moves image up or left.

But these functions need different number of rows - `height` instead of `width`

```
    for y in range(height):
        new_image.append([])
```

---

**EDIT:**

My full code which I used for tests:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class ImageProcesser:  # PEP8: `CamelCaseNames` for classes
    
    def __init__(self, image, path):
        self.image = image
        self.data = np.asarray(image)
        self.data_type = type(self.data)
        self.data_shape = self.data.shape
        self.path = path

    def rotate_clockwise(self):  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for functions
        print("Rotating Clockwise")
        
        height = self.data_shape[0]
        width  = self.data_shape[1]

        new_image = []
        for _ in range(width):
            new_image.append([])

        for y in range(height):
            for x in range(width):
                new_image[x].append(self.data[-y][x])

        return np.asarray(new_image)

    def rotate_counter(self):
        print("Rotating Counter-Clockwise")
        
        height = self.data_shape[0]
        width  = self.data_shape[1]

        new_image = []
        for _ in range(width):
            new_image.append([])

        for y in range(height):
            for x in range(width):
                new_image[x].append(self.data[y][-x])

        return np.asarray(new_image)

    def transpose(self):
        print("Transpose")
        
        height = self.data_shape[0]
        width  = self.data_shape[1]

        new_image = []
        for _ in range(width):
            new_image.append([])

        for y in range(height):
            for x in range(width):
                new_image[x].append(self.data[y][x])

        return np.asarray(new_image)

    def flip_horizontal(self):
        print("Flip Horizontal")
        
        height = self.data_shape[0]
        width  = self.data_shape[1]

        new_image = []
        for _ in range(height):
            new_image.append([])

        for y in range(height):
            for x in range(width):
                new_image[y].append(self.data[y][-x])

        return np.asarray(new_image)

    def flip_vertical(self):
        print("Flip Vertical")
        
        height = self.data_shape[0]
        width  = self.data_shape[1]

        new_image = []
        for _ in range(height):
            new_image.append([])

        for y in range(height):
            for x in range(width):
                new_image[y].append(self.data[-y][x])

        return np.asarray(new_image)

    def move_horizontal(self, step=0):
        print("Move Horizontal")
        
        height = self.data_shape[0]
        width  = self.data_shape[1]

        new_image = []
        for _ in range(height):
            new_image.append([])

        for y in range(height):
            for x in range(width):
                new_image[y].append(self.data[y][(x-step)%width])

        return np.asarray(new_image)

    def move_vertical(self, step=0):
        print("Move Vertical")
        
        height = self.data_shape[0]
        width  = self.data_shape[1]

        new_image = []
        for _ in range(height):
            new_image.append([])

        for y in range(height):
            for x in range(width):
                new_image[y].append(self.data[(y-step)%height][x])

        return np.asarray(new_image)

    def save_image(self, new_image):
        self.image = Image.fromarray(new_image)
        
        self.data = np.asarray(self.image)
        self.data_shape = self.data.shape
        
        #self.image.save(path)
        
        plt.imshow(self.image)
        plt.show()

# --- main ---

path = "/home/furas/test/image.jpg"
image = Image.open(path)

image = ImageProcesser(image, path)

image.save_image(image.rotate_clockwise())
image.save_image(image.rotate_clockwise())

image.save_image(image.rotate_counter())
image.save_image(image.rotate_counter())

image.save_image(image.transpose())
image.save_image(image.transpose())

image.save_image(image.flip_horizontal())
image.save_image(image.flip_horizontal())

image.save_image(image.flip_vertical())
image.save_image(image.flip_vertical())

image.save_image(image.move_horizontal(100))
image.save_image(image.move_horizontal(-200))
image.save_image(image.move_horizontal(100))

image.save_image(image.move_vertical(50))
image.save_image(image.move_vertical(-100))
image.save_image(image.move_vertical(50))
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Thank you. Now that it works I'll be sure to work on optimizing the syntax.